# How to I replay a GET request?

Tags: django, cookies, request, postman, replay

I have a django website, the first page is a simple login form.
After a successful login, the user is redirected to `/home/` url. i.e. to view `/home/` url you are required to login (session based).
I'm trying to replay the request to `/home/` using a tool like Postman (but other tools could work too I guess).
I open chrome dev tools, network tab, copy all the request headers (cookie header is also there), and paste it in the tool, I copy the url and do a GET request.
This does not work and I my website returns the login page.
Means, my website does not consider the Postman request to be authenticated.  Why?
Isn't the session cookie is how  the server check whether the user is logged in?
  I copied everything from the request headers in chrome, so how is that the browser (chrome) and the tool (Postman) are treated differently?
My website does not uses HTTPS, though I still don't understand how it would make a difference.

Comment: Can you try to insert `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/home/'` into `settings.py`

Comment: Share your code. also share error you are getting in server side while calling url from postman.

Comment: wont help. BTW, I've tested it with another sites which require authentication (simple login). Still wont help. It seems like the browser send something that I don't send with Postman.. I don't know what it is

Comment: I'm not sure what is confusing you here. Yes, the session cookie is how the auth status is determined; and the cookie is in your browser, not in postman.

Comment: But how the website (the server) knows the cookie is in my browser? Isn't it solely because of the header "Cookie:.."?  Cause I copied this header as well. So I somewhat "stole" the session cookie from my browser, so I thought it should work

Comment: Maybe I'm confusing but, what if, in your postman test, fill the Authorization tab ? if you set the type as 'basic authorization' you may submit the login and password. for me it worked fine.

Comment: @user3599803 I think there are several questions in this question. Please do some filleting and cut your problem into smaller peaces. Don't be shy. Ask 5 questions with each one particular problem (not one question with 5 problems).